# Order products by price in magento without stock

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to sort the products collection by price, but these products disappears when i add (bold)

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->
addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => '1'))-**>
addAttributeToSort('price', 'DESC');**
```

I want to sort them although there is no stock, does anyone know I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

For the stock I think you ll find everything you need on eshop_cataloginventory_stock_item with the flag is_in_stock